# sortable li and automatically sortable div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to sortable li, when li is sortable then automatically div with index also sortable. When I exchange `item 1` and `item 2` or any other, then on div side with class result, move div with id="get-item" as same as li item.

How this is possible. thanks.

**My code**

```js
$("#sortable1").sortable();
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}

.result {
  color: red;
}

#get-item {
  background: #b0b6b9;
  margin-left: 181px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 113px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<ul id="sortable1" class="">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item1'>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item2'>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item3'>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item4'>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item5'>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<div class="result">
  <div id="get-item">1</div>
  <div id="get-item">2</div>
  <div id="get-item">3</div>
  <div id="get-item">4</div>
  <div id="get-item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how are you moving `li`s?

Comment: `id` must be unique. `id="get-item" id="get-item" id="get-item"` is invalid.

Comment: narendra jadhav update my code..i want also sortable div on the base of li sortable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`stop()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) event inside of [`$("#sortable1").sortable()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable) like this

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    stop: function(evt, ui) {
       //Put your logic here...
    }
});
```

After that you can get all `li` tag inside of `stop` event and then loop for that and set the value in `result`  div

**Note** your component id should be unique it should not be common. Instead of applying css using **id** use `class` property.

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1").sortable({
    stop: function(evt, ui) {
      let resultDiv = $('div.get-item');
      $.each($(this).find('li'), function(i, el) {
        $(resultDiv[i]).text($(el).attr('value'));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}

.result {
  color: red;
}

.get-item {
  background: #b0b6b9;
  margin-left: 181px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 113px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<ul id="sortable1" class="">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item1' value=1 >Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item2' value=2>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item3' value=3>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item4' value=4>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item5' value=5>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<div class="result">
  <div class="get-item">1</div>
  <div class="get-item">2</div>
  <div class="get-item">3</div>
  <div class="get-item">4</div>
  <div class="get-item">5</div>
</div>
```

---

**Demo using insertBefore and insertAfter**

You could also use [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) and [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

```js
function insertAt(parent, element, index, dir) {
    var el = parent.children().eq(index);

    element[dir == 'top' ? 'insertBefore' : 'insertAfter'](el);
}

$(function() {
    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        stop: function(evt, ui) {
            let parent = $('.result'),
                el = parent.find('.' + ui.item.attr('id')),
                dir = 'top';

            if (ui.offset.top > ui.originalPosition.top) {
                dir = 'bottom';
            }
            insertAt(parent, el, ui.item.index(), dir);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.get-item {
  margin-left: 181px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 113px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.item1 {
  background: red;
}

.item2 {
  background: pink;
}

.item3 {
  background: brown;
}

.item4 {
  background: orange;
}

.item5 {
  background: #5c5c5c;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item1'>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item2'>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item3'>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item4'>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item5'>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<div class="result">
  <div class="get-item item1">1</div>
  <div class="get-item item2">2</div>
  <div class="get-item item3">3</div>
  <div class="get-item item4">4</div>
  <div class="get-item item5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks narendra its good but i want move div not enter text.move get_item class div up and down, divs contain many different attribute.

Comment: div with class also sortable with number.

Comment: narendra have any idea how to possible this.